# Jenkins-x cluster set up failed when specifying options like --nodes, master-size and others

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-x

if I run `jx create cluster aws` ->  it creates the cluster on aws without any issues but if I won't to specify some options  like this:

```
jx create cluster aws --zones us-east-2b --nodes=2 --node-size=t2.micro --master-size=t2.micro
```

Then it fails constantly, whatever I tried to change, giving out these kind of errors for almost all options:

```
Error: unknown flag: - -node-size and the same for other options. Options were taken from here https://jenkins-x.io/commands/jx_create_cluster_aws/
```

Setting up the cluster with kops with whatever options don't have any issues

Comment: I notice some of your example args use the equals sign and `--zones` does not. Have you tried omitting the equals?

Comment: It also appears that there were several AWS fixes in [the latest release](https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/releases/tag/v1.3.86); what version are you using?

Comment: Yes, I've tried different variations, like this jx create cluster aws   --name aws1.cluster.k8s.local  --state s3://some-bucket-here --zones us-east-2b --node-count 2 --node-size t2.micro --master-size t2.micro . Didn't work, same errors.

Answer (score 3):

I asked about this in a comment, but the actual *answer* appears to be that you are on a version of `jx` that doesn't match the documentation. Because this is my experience with a freshly downloaded binary:

```
$ ./jx create cluster aws --verbose=true --zones=us-west-2a,us-west-2b,us-west-2c --cluster-name=sample --node-size=5 --master-size=m5.large
kops not found
kubectl not found
helm not found
? Missing required dependencies, deselect to avoid auto installing:  [Use arrows to move, type to filter]
❯ ◉  kops
  ◉  kubectl
  ◉  helm
? nodes [? for help] (3)
^C

$ ./jx --version
1.3.90
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see what version of `jx` you are using via:

```
jx version
```

you can check the options of a command via `jx help create cluster aws` or by browsing the [online CLI reference](https://jenkins-x.io/commands/jx/) for the command: [jx create cluster aws](https://jenkins-x.io/commands/jx_create_cluster_aws/)